# Delayed Centered Popup Javascript using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, popup, settimeout, invalid-argument

Trying to get a centered popup to display after a set value of time, something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function popup(url) {
    var width = 300;
    var height = 200;
    var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
    var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
    var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
    params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
    params += ', directories=no';
    params += ', location=no';
    params += ', menubar=no';
    params += ', resizable=no';
    params += ', scrollbars=no';
    params += ', status=no';
    params += ', toolbar=no';
    newwin = window.open(url, 'windowname5', params);
    if (window.focus) {
        newwin.focus()
    }
    setTimeout(popup('`test/login.html'), 5000);
    return false;
}

//-->
//]]>
</script>
```

but the popup never displays. If I write it like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function popup(url) {
            var width = 300;
            var height = 200;
            var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
            var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
            var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
            params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
            params += ', directories=no';
            params += ', location=no';
            params += ', menubar=no';
            params += ', resizable=no';
            params += ', scrollbars=no';
            params += ', status=no';
            params += ', toolbar=no';
            newwin = window.open(url, 'windowname5', params);
            if (window.focus) {
                newwin.focus()
            }

            return false;

        }
        setTimeout(popup('`test/login.html'), 5000);
        //-->
        //]]>
    </script>
```

the popup displays immediately, but then I receve an Invalid Argument error. Suggestions?

Comment: setTimeout(function(){popup('`test/login.html')}, 5000);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setTimout` takes a function as its first parameter.  `popup(...)` does not return a function.  Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {popup('`test/login.html');}, 5000)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, you placed the `setTimeout` within the body of the `popup()` function. The body of that function won't be run until the function is called. So, you're right in your second attempt to place the `setTimeout` outside of the `popup()` body.

The other problem is that you need to pass either [a function or code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) to `setTimeout()`:

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, delay);
```

Like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    popup('`test/login.html'); // provided that tick-mark is right...
}, 5000);
```

Whereas your existing method will execute `popup()` immediately and provide no function to the timout function:

```
setTimeout(popup('`test/login.html'), 5000);
```